# Vue-i18n Single File Component Not Working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I am trying to implement v-i18n to my project with sfc method. I couldn't make it work. I will not make you confuse with my project, that's why just modified with adding 10-15 lines of code to official v-i18n sfc example.

This is very simply shows my question.

For those who prefer check this very tiny question project on github

> https://github.com/berkansivri/V-i18n-Question

**Component1.vue**

```
<template>
    <p>{{$t('lang')}}</p>
</template>

<i18n>
{
  "en":{
    "lang" : "English"
  },
  "es":{
    "lang": "Espanol"
  }
}
</i18n>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <label for="locale">locale</label>
    <select v-model="locale">
      <option>en</option>
      <option>es</option>
    </select>
    <p>message: {{ $t('hello') }}</p>
    <Comp1></Comp1>
  </div>
</template>

<i18n>
{
  "en": {
    "hello": "hello"
  },
  "es": {
    "hello": "hola"
  }
}
</i18n>

<script>
import Comp1 from './components/component1'
export default {
  components:{
    Comp1
  },
  name: 'App',
  data () { return { locale: 'en' } },
  watch: {
    locale (val) {
      this.$i18n.locale = val
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

So, multiple `<i18n>`tag in multiple components. I just modified $i18n.locale from App.vue but it did not fire related i18n function `$t('lang')` on Component1, just modifies `$t('hello')` on itself.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Apparently you rely on [this guide](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/sfc.html#basic-usage). So, did you install [vue-i18n-loader](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n-loader) and configure vue.config.js for it?

Comment: @vahdet Yes, you can check my github repo. I did not copy everything to make question unreadable, even it is very tiny.

Answer (score 1):

using vue devtools u will find out that messages of $i18n in single file component is different from each other, so they are different objects.

u need to do is:

i18n.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from '@/lang'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'cn',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages
})

export default i18n
```

App.vue

```
import i18n from "./i18n.js"
i18n.locale = "en"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior of Single file components. If you want to change all locales of all components you can use:

```
locale (val) {
  // this.$i18n.locale = val
  this.$root.$i18n.locale = val
}
```

See this [issue](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/411).